Doubts on "An Intensive Introduction to Cryptography" exercise about Shannon's entropy
I was going through the exercises in An Intensive Introduction to Cryptography (see full PDF here), and in particular, I had some doubts on Exercise 0.12 (found on page 42). Here is the relevant section transcribed:

Exercise 0.12 Recall the definition of a distribution $\mu$ over some finite set $S$. Shannon defined the entropy of a distribution $\mu$, denoted by $H(\mu)$, to be $\sum_{x \in S} \mu(x) \log(1 / \mu(x))$. The idea is that if $\mu$ is a distribution of entropy $k$, then encoding members of $\mu$ will require $k$ bits, in an amortized sense. In this exercise we justify this definition. Let $\mu$ be such that $H(\mu) = k$.

Prove that for every one to one function $F \colon S \to \{0, 1\}^*$, $\mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mu} |F(x)| \ge k$.


To me, this statement seems incorrect as is, unless I'm misunderstanding something. A trivial counterexample can be seen with the following distribution over three elements. Let $S = \{a, b, c\}$ and $F(a) = 0$, $F(b) = 1$, and $F(c) = 01$. Finally, let $\mu(a) = 1/2$, $\mu(b) = 1/4$, and $\mu(c) = 1/4$. The expectation to calculate is
$$\sum_{x \in S} \mu(x) \, |F(x)| = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 = \frac{5}{4}.$$
The entropy is given by
$$\sum_{x \in S} \mu(x) \log_2(1/\mu(x)) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 2 = \frac{3}{2}.$$
But clearly $1.25$ is not greater than or equal to $1.5$, which is why this feels problematic. Even if one were to make the logarithm in the definition of entropy use base $e$, the problem would still remain (choose a uniform distribution, for example). The only other thing I can think of is that I am interpreting the notation incorrectly (for example, the notation of $|F(x)|$ is not explicitly explained, although I have interpreted it to be the length of the string).
Am I missing something, or is this statement as is incorrect? If it is incorrect, what statement is the author intending? (Note that I am not asking for a proof of the fact, as I want to figure that out myself).

What is ${0,1}^*$? One could take a look at your notes but it would be much  better if you provide all the details (definitions) in your posting.

I suspect that the issue here lies at the meaning of

For every one to one function $F:S \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$

Typically one wants to deal with streams of symbols from $S$, think something like "$abacaba$" and encode them into a sequence of bits using $F$  "$F(a)F(b)F(a)F(c)F(a)F(b)F(a)$" which in your example would be "$01001010$".
The Catch Usually you do want to restrict yourself to $F$ so that from the bit sequence you can uniquely determine the input sequence.
I suspect that there may be a typo in the definition of $F$. It should probably read

For every one to one function $F : S^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$

That is to say, every sequence of symbols is mapped to a unique sequence of bits.
In the example you gave the sequence "$ab$" is mapped to $F(a)F(b) = 01$ and so is the sequence "$c$" since $F(c) = 01$ so it is not one to one over all sequences of symbols. I suspect that this means that your counter example does not meet the criteria.
In fact one can show that the best possible encoding when $\mu(a) = 1/2, \mu(b) = \mu(c) = 1/4$ (lookup Hoffman encodings for more info on this) from which the symbols can be uniquely determined from the bits is given by
$$F(a) = 0, \ F(b) = 10, \ F(c) = 11$$
and this achieves an average length of $(1/2)1 + (1/4)2 + (1/4)2 = 2 > 3/2$

I see! Thank you very much for the help!
